# How to render page inside a folder in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2017

Sorry if my question is confusing what im trying to ask is how can i render a page that is located in a folder

for example:

my MainWindow.xaml is located in the root folder

i want to render a page located in "ProjectName/Pages" inside a

In case you are still confused this

```
ProjectName
-- Pages          <--- The page i want to render is in this folder
-- App.config
-- App.xaml
-- MainWndow.xaml <--- i want to render the page here
```

i dont want to have both page and window in the root of the folder, it will look too messy

Comment: Have you tried to just move the page to the desired folder? The pages are classes inside an assembly after compilation, the folder structure doesn't matter.

Comment: the page is already in the desired folder, i cant get it to render i know its something simple but i literally just got into coding with c# like a few days ago i know im missing something but no matter where i look and codes i try i can not get it to render on my mainwindow

Comment: What error you get?

Comment: right now i deleted everything and created a new project thinking that might help. Ill let you know once i find the code i used again in the mean time, do you by any chance know of any code i could use to try and see if it works?

Comment: To render a page in you want you need to include it in your `Window` `XAML`. And try to use `UserControl` for now. People get the wrong idea with `Page`'s in `WPF`.

Answer (score 1):

Add a new `Page` to your "Pages" folder. Right-click on the folder in the Solution Explorer in Visual Studio and select Add->New Item and then choose a `Page` and call it "Page1.xaml" or whatever.

You could then display the `Page` in your window using a `Frame` like this:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Window12" Height="300" Width="300">
    <StackPanel>
        <Frame x:Name="frame" Source="/Pages/Page1.xaml" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```